# Recovering sheaf from sheaf on base.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

From Ravi Vakil's  "Fundamental of Algebraic geometry",

Suppose we have a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$, and a nice base $\{B_i\}$ on $X$. Then consider the information $(\{\mathcal{F}(B_i)\},\{φ_{ij} : \mathcal{F}(B_i) → \mathcal{F}(B_j)\}$, which is a subset of the information contained in the sheaf.

We can recover the entire sheaf from this information. We claim $$\mathcal{F}(U) = \{(f_i ∈ \mathcal{F}(B_i))_{B_i \subset U} : φ_{ij}(f_i) = f_j\}$$

We are recovering the set $\mathcal{F}(U)$ by gathering all sections of $\mathcal{F}(B_i)$ since $\cup B_i = U$.

However, I am not sure what to make of the condition $\phi_{ij}(f_i) =f_j$ So $\mathcal{F}(U)$ is the collection of all  sections $f_i \in \mathcal{F}(B_i)$ whose restrictions are sections of $\mathcal{F}(B_j)$. If $B_i \subset B_j$ this is true for all $f_i$.

What happens in the case that $B_j \not \subset B_i$? How exactly is this condition recovering the set $\mathcal{F}(U)$?

Comment: Does he write this? My guess would be that he's only defined $\varphi_{ij}$ if $B_j \subset B_i$. I think you're missing a lot of conditions and words.

Comment: Since there is always a restriction map, then every section $f_i$ is mapped to some $f_j$. In that case, what is the point of adding this restriction? Why not just take the collection of $f_i \in \mathcal{F}(B_i)$ for every $B_i$ covering $U$?

Comment: He doesn't say so explicitly as far as I can tell, but what Hoot is saying is pretty clearly what was meant.

Comment: Possibly, it is coming from a set of notes but I guess I don't understand the necessity of the condition at all.

Comment: @asdvn It looks like you're misunderstanding the notation, or I'm misunderstanding you. The set $\mathcal{F}(U)$ is taken to be a set of *families* of sections over basic open subsets of $U$. The families that are allowed into $\mathcal{F}(U)$ are the ones that are compatible with the restriction maps; that is, we take the families of sections over basic open subsets of $U$ such that any section on a basic open set is a restriction of the section on any basic open set containing it.

Comment: Oh ok. That clarifies my misunderstanding. Thank you!

Comment: I think that the way to think about it is as follows:

For any point $p \in U$, we know what the stalks $\mathscr F_p$ are. Now since $\mathscr F$ is a sheaf, then $\mathscr F(U) \cong \mathscr F^{sh}(U) = \{\text{ compatible germs of } \mathscr F \text{ over } U\}$. An element $(s_p)_{p \in U} \in \mathscr F^{sh}(U)$ consists of compatible germs if for all $p \in U$, there exists a basic open $B \subset U$ containing $p$, and an element $t \in \mathscr F(B)$ such that for all $q \in B$, we have $t_q = s_q \in \mathscr F_q$.

Comment: Since we can describe the compatible germs in this way, then we have the set $\mathscr F(U)$. Hence we recover the sheaf.